# Soundex on a Large Table

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I had a table of names, containing 200,000 rows. This has now been updated to include over 11 million rows.

The table is queried using a *SOUNDS LIKE 'str'* and the result is then passed through levenshtein_ratio() [a custom function that compares string similarity]. This worked quickly with the 200,000 rows, but with 11 million rows it is now taking two seconds.

I believe I can make this work a lot quicker by saving the soundex of each name, indexing that column, and then searching by this. But am concerned that the levenshtein_ratio() will be slow as it is now being few with potentially 2,000-3,000 result.

I am interested to know how database professional would consider approaching this issue. In particular, I am wondering if it might be better to compute the levenshtein_ratio in PHP.

Comment: You might want to look at http://falseisnotnull.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/levenshtein-and-levenshtein_ratio-functions-for-mysql/

Comment: I am finding that adding a column to my table with the soundex stored, searching that, and then using similar_text() in PHP is proving very quick. Would be nice to do it all in MySQL, but this is working quicker than the old method on 200K rows.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634995/implementation-of-levenshtein-distance-for-mysql-fuzzy-search and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338889/how-to-find-similar-results-and-sort-by-similarity for alternatives, including a C implementation ready to use in MySQL as a UDF: https://github.com/jmcejuela/Levenshtein-MySQL-UDF , using Lucene or Sphinx or using FULLTEXT indexes